# How to use $http.post of angular js to post data in django forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I am trying to post the form data without page refresh,first i used ajax call to prevent page refresh.

Here is my ajax code for post:-

```
$('#post-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!")  // sanity check
    create_post();

    function create_post() {
    console.log("create post is working!") // sanity check
    $.ajax({
        url : "blog/create_post/", // the endpoint
        type : "POST", // http method
        data : { 
            body : $('#id_text').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken : $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()

        }, // data sent with the post request

        // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
           console.log("Hey Its Done please Chcek the Updated List")
            console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console

        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
};
});
```

This is my views.py:-

```
def index(request):

    response_data= {}

    return JsonResponse({"body":list(q.text for q in Blog.objects.order_by('-id')[:10])})


def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_text = request.POST.get('body')
        post = Blog(text=post_text)
        post.save()
        return JsonResponse({"body":list(q.text for q in Blog.objects.order_by('-id')[:10])})
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

So my ajax is woking fine but what i wanted to do use $http.post of angular.js so that i can make a post request and pass the data of the form to the server side,and on success of that post my view just get automatically updated.
here is my app.js:-

```
$http.post('blog/create_post').then(successCallback, errorCallback);
        function successCallback(response){
            var temp=response.data;
            $scope.products = temp.body
            console.log($scope.products);
        }
        function errorCallback(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
```

And this my template:-

```
{%load staticfiles%}
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body ng-controller='movie'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/themes/blue/pace-theme-minimal.min.css" />
<h1>What's On Your Mind?</h1>

<form method="POST" id="post-form">

        {{ form.as_p }}
    <div id="results"></div> 
    <input type="submit" value="Post" class="tiny button">
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>

    <div ng-repeat="item in products track by $index">
        <ul>
            <li ng-bind='item'></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


<!--{% for i in "xxxxxxxxxx" %}
<p id='item{{forloop.counter0}}'></p>
{% endfor %}-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'blog/js/main.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'blog/js/app.js' %}"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Please Help!